# .Net core Razor Pages add many child rows

Tags: one-to-many, razor-pages

How would I handle a model with many children in a razor page `Create` page?

I have the following models:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public string ClientName;
    public DateTime InvoiceDate;
    public List<InvoiceItem> InvoiceItems;
}

public class InvoiceItem
{
    public string ProductName;
    public decimal Qty;
    public decimal UnitPrice;
}
```

I want to add a button in my `Invoice` `Create` page that says "Add new item". I will then add (using ajax) a new line on the form with a new `InvoiceItem` - this I know how to do.

What I don't know is how to set up everything so all the invoice lines will get recognized by the `OnPostAsync()` method and saved in the database together with the `Invoice`.

Any pointers or examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Use a sequential index for each item when you generate the input elements: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding#binding-related-collections-to-a-complex-object